# else if in Android Studio

Tags: android, if-statement

I am trying to run my app but I can't because it doesn't accept my code.

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_home)
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
        else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_procedures);
        fragment = new ProceduresFragment();
        else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_map);
        fragment = new ProceduresFragment();
        return loadFragment(fragment);
}
```

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss some brackets :

```
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_home) {
            fragment = new HomeFragment(); 
        }
        else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_procedures) {
            fragment = new ProceduresFragment();
        }
            else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_map) {
            fragment = new ProceduresFragment();
        }
    return loadFragment(fragment);
    }
```